# How to parse a CSR when multiple DN OU's are present?

Tags: python, cryptography, x509, pyopenssl, csr

[Python OpenSSL](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api.html) parses these request files very neatly, but the data is stored in a dictionary. This means when it parses the certificate and finds two distinct values for OU (e.g. OU=Strategic Initiatives OU=Management), it only returns one of them. I need both.

The [Python Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#x-509-certificate-object) library seems to be more granular, but the documentation is awful and I can't figure out how to extract just the text from the fields rather than the strange objects they return. And I'm not sure how if it handles multiple DN OUs.

How do I parse a CSR when multiple OU's are present?

Comment: pyopenssl `X509Name.get_components()` returns a list a 2-tuples, not a dict. If you have multiple OUs they'll all be in there.

Comment: @JamesKPolk this is actually not the case. My second OU does not appear.

Comment: It does for me. If you want help with your code, show your code and your cert. That's how SO works.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I am telling you that printing the output of the same `print(X509Name.get_components())` omits the second OU I have, and I've confirmed the second OU exists. Is it a version issue?

Comment: I can't read your mind or remotely view your data. Since you won't post your code or your data I have to run my own experiments. My experiments show that for a cert I created with two OU fields `X509Name.get_components()` 1) returns a list of 2-tuples, not a dict, and 2) that list contains both OU components. Furthermore, the [documentation](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#x509name-objects) that *you link to* clearly states that `X509Name.get_components()` returns a list of 2-tuples, not a dict.